# when I tried to make a call to this method "setupWithViewPager()" i didn't find it

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

in parent class because parent class are extends from LinearLayout and This function is in class HorizontalScrollView how can i fix this problem

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this); 
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
    TableLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs); 
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); 
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Your code looks completely fine, what problem are you facing?

Comment: Yes because instead of TabLayout, you have used TableLayout

Comment: you are right it's working now  @AshishKumar

Answer (score 1):

Simple typing error here:

```
TableLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

Should be:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```